# Integral of a function avoiding hypergeometric functions

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations

I'm solving the following differential equation: $$uy''(u)+\gamma y'(u)+\frac{1}{u(1-u)}=0,~~\gamma=constant$$ For that, I transform this equation into a first orer one: $$uf'(u)+\gamma f(u)+\frac{1}{u(1-u)}=0,~~\gamma=constant$$ To solve these diff. eq. first I find the homogeneous solution, $f_h(u)=c_1~u^{-\gamma}$ (so the homogeneous solution of my original equation will be $y_h(u)=c_1~\frac{u^{-\gamma+1}}{-\gamma+1}+c_2$). Then I find the particular solution as $f_p(u)=c_1(u)~u^{-\gamma}$.$$ $$ I get $$c_1(u)=\int \frac{u^{\gamma-2}}{1-u}+c_3$$ If I solve this with mathematica I get a solution involving an hypergeometric function and I would like to get something that doesn't involve hypergeometric functions.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It is entirely possible that you cannot avoid special functions of some sort here.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have some special function, but not hypergeometric. Is this possible? I don't know, some combination of elementary functions and a beta function or something like this would be nice. I'm doing a simulation and I need to avoid the hypergeometric functions.

Comment: In fact, I don't know to do the integral by hand, because $\gamma$ is not integer. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Finally I found that the solution of the integral can be expressed as:$$c_1(u)=-B_u(\gamma-1,0)+const$$ where $B_u$ es the incomplete beta function

:)